# this vs. (this) in Scala

Tags: scala, circe

I use the Scala circe library to convert objects of the case class `Message` to JSON and also to create `Message` objects from their JSON representation. This class is implemented as follows:

```
import io.circe
import io.circe.generic.semiauto.{deriveDecoder, deriveEncoder}
import io.circe.parser
import io.circe.syntax._

object Message {
  implicit val measurementDecoder = deriveDecoder[Message]
  implicit val measurementEncoder = deriveEncoder[Message]

  def fromJson(jsonString: String): Either[circe.Error, Message] =
    parser.decode[Message](jsonString)
}

case class Message(id: Int, text: String) {
  def toJson() = (this).asJson.noSpaces
  def toJson2() = this.asJson.noSpaces // syntax error: No implicit arguments of type: Encoder[Message.this.type]
}
```

My point is the implementation of the method `toJson`. While this variant works

```scala
def toJson() = (this).asJson.noSpaces
```

the variant

```scala
def toJson() = this.asJson.noSpaces
```

leads to the syntax error

> `No implicit arguments of type: Encoder[Message.this.type]`

So what's the difference between `this` and `(this)` in Scala?

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: The syntax error is: `No implicit arguments of type: Encoder[Message.this.type]`, but only if the parens around `this`are omitted.

Comment: Now I am confused. In the first version of this question, you had a compile error. Now, it is a syntax error. Those are two very different things. Which of the two is it? In particular, the *text* of the error message does not sound like a syntax error.

Comment: I can't reproduce it: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/yBZzq0deQ5i8QOW87R5puA/2 - Which means that either the error is not real, is only some bug in your IDE. Or, the code you shared is not enough to reproduce the error; please create an **Scastie** that actually reproduces the error and then edit the question.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by [Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4111404/luis-miguel-mej%C3%ADa-su%C3%A1rez) it is neither a syntax nor a compile error, but a bug in the current version of the IntelliJ IDEA Scala plugin (version 2021.3.17). Using parentheses is a way to get around this problem.